# How can I insert values into the list part of a dictionary of(string, list(of string))?

Tags: vb.net, list, dictionary, visual-studio-2012

I'm working with a `dictionary(of string, list(of string))` in VB to store some text data pulled from large .csv files.

The dictionary.key is just a date string like "2012-12-12", and the corresponding list value contains all of the files that are associated with that date.

Using a `StreamReader` and a `line.split`, I can pull out the date string and compare it to the dictionary. If the dictionary does not contain that date, I want to insert it as a new key, then add the filename to the list for that key. This will loop through the whole file, then continue through every file the user has selected, using the same dictionary. Eventually I should see 4 or 5 file names per date, with no duplicate file names per date allowed.

What is the correct way to use `dictionary.add` method to do this?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? Please post your code and explain where you are stuck.

Comment: At first I tried a simple "If.." statement: `If Not dictionary.ContainsKey(string) then dictionary.add(string, string)` thinking the second string would automatically get placed into the corresponding list. This generated an error "Value of type String cannot be converted to Systems.Collections.Generic.List(Of String)".

Comment: Well, yes, A `string` is not a list of strings... When adding to the dictionary you need to add a new _list_ and add the value to this list.

Comment: Next I tried creating a list of the file names separately, then inserting that list into the dictionary under the corresponding key value, but that just seems excessive and hard to manage with a potentially unknown amount of dates and files to process.

Comment: That makes sense Oded, let me try that out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

something like this?

```
Dim key as String = "asdf"
If Not dict.ContainsKey(key) Then
    dict.Add(key, New List(Of String)(New String() {"1", "2", "3"}))
    Dim values = dict(key)
    If not values.Contains("some value") Then
        values.Add("some value")
    End If
End If
```

or something like this:

```
Dim key as String = "asdf"
If Not dict.ContainsKey(key) Then
    dict.Add(key, New List(Of String))
    dict(key).Add("1")
    dict(key).Add("2")
    ... and however many more values here ...
End If
```

Comment: Your first example worked great thanks. Now how can I check the  values stored in the list that corresponds to a certain key against another string, then insert that string into that key's list if it isn't already there?

Comment: @Mellonjollie I updated the first snippet to show you how to do that. you just get a reference to the list identified by the key you're working with and just check if the list contains the value. if not, add it.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much. I have no clue why our textbook never covers dictionaries or lists.